# DsoFramer disables running Excel instances

Tags: excel, dsoframer

I'm using DsoFramer control to display Excel documents within my application. Here's the problem: if i have Excel 2007 running as a standalone application before launching my application, and then launch mine and open an Excel document within it, then standalone Excel becomes inaccessible (can't be alt+tabbed to) for as long as my application displays Excel document. Could this be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

Generally dso framer connects your program to the running excel process. So you could use excel features through its COM interfaces. If you have a review on dso framer control source code, it seems that the control couldn't do any thing whenever it is in modal mode or similar modes like that. Hence when your excel object (through dso framer) be in a modal mode or etc, another excel instances running on your system can't do any thing and they would be inaccessible. To remove this problem, try reducing dso framer control modal modes (or aforementioned modes that you seen on the dso framer source code) in your program. I working on a project that has similar dso framer application.